# Order plotly figure by CategoricalDtype order

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python, categorical-data

The goal is to visualize boxplots for each group in order. Group is of`pd.CategoricalDtype` and ordered.
I do not manage to get plotly to respect the order. Instead, it only sorts alphabetically.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('CAACCBAA'), 'values': np.random.random(8)})
cat_ordered = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['B', 'C', 'A'], ordered=True)
df['group'] = df['group'].astype(cat_ordered)

fig = px.box(df, x='group', y='values', 
             category_orders={'group': list(df.group.cat.categories)})
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')
fig.show()
```

The expected order would be B - C - A.
[image: px.box output]

I believe plotly does not take over the order from the pandas dataframe, but manually setting it does not help either.

`plotly==5.17.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly doesn't seem to treat `list` and [`Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) objects the same way.

Passing the latter (that is returned by [`categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.categories.html)) fixes the issue :

```
fig = px.box(df, x='group', y='values', template='plotly_dark',
             category_orders={'group': cat_ordered.categories}) # <-- updated
                                 # or df.group.cat.categories

fig.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Even taking the extra effort to create the plot in dark mode, too. Thanks a lot for your help!